# Ubuntu: How to set system wide keyboard shortcut independent of sessions?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I set a system wide shortcut in Ubuntu? That shortcut (for example, <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) should work even if no user is logged in. If pressed, a command should be executed. I tried xbindkeys but it doesn't work once the screen saver is activated. Shortcuts set in a desktop environment also only work if a user is logged in.